# Check data correctness before export to xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have class like that:

```
public class Animal
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(20)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Weight { get; set; }
   public double Height { get; set; }
   public int AnimalID { get; set; }
}
```

and I have to generate XML using this, but before it, I have to check correctness of this data (e.g. `Weight` cannot be longer than 100, `AnimalID` should be in range 0 to 9).

How should I do this?
I have blackout...

Comment: I would write a Validator using [fluentvalidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, I can use everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) from DataAnnotations namespace. This way you can wrap the object in try/catch block like below and catch 
ValidationExceptions:

```
try {
    Animal animal = GetAnimal();
}catch(ValidationException ex)
{}

public class Animal
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(20)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [Required, RangeAttribute(0,100)]
   public double Weight { get; set; }
   public double Height { get; set; }
   [Required, RangeAttribute(0, 9)]
   public int AnimalID { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if you are using MVC then you can use methods like ModelState.IsValid etc.